# Redirect APPCRASH Dumps (Or turn them off)

Tags: c++, c, windows, crash-dumps, memory-dump

I have an application (didn't write it) that is producing APPCRASH dumps in C:\Windows\SysWOW64. The application while dumping is crippled, but operating at bare minimum capacity to not *lose data*. The issue is that these dumps are so large that the system is spending most of it's time writing these and the application is falling far behind in processing and will start losing data soon.

The plan is to either entirely disable it, or mount it to a RAM drive and purge them as soon as they hit the RAM drive.

Now I've looked into using this key:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But all it does is generate a second dump now instead of redirect the original.

The dump is named:

dump-2013_03_31-15_23_55_772.dmp

This is generally the realm of developers on Windows (with stuff like C/C++) so I'd like to hit them up, don't think ServerFault could get me any answers on this.

Additionally: It's not cycling dump files (they'll fill the 20GBs left on the hard drive), so I'm not sure if this is Windows behavior or custom code in the app (if it is... ick!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a DumpFile, an app has to call the function  "MiniDumpWriteDump" so this is not a behavior of the system or something you can control, it is application driven. If it dumps on crashes, it uses "SetUnhandledExceptionFilter" to set its own handling routine, before(!) the OS takes over. Unfortunately I didn't found a way to overwrite this handler from an other process, so the only hope left is, that there is a register entry for the app switching the behavior or change the path (as my applications have it for exactly the reason you describe).